# Apache Tomcat rewrite

Tags: apache, .htaccess, tomcat

What I'm trying to do is setup a rewrite rule so that when a URL is entered it will be displayed as example.com/test

So for example, I'm trying to do this if it's even possible.

I've set the CNAME of site.example.com to point to site.devEnvironment.com (dev Remote Environment on the vendors side)

If a user visits **site.example.com** the URL will be re-written to something along these lines **test.com/test**

What I have so far but doesn't seem to be working, when I visit site.example.com it stays as is

```
# rewrite rules for site.example.com - owned by Company A
RewriteCond %{http_host} ^site\.example\.com [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{http_host} ^www\.site\.example\.com [NC]
RewriteRule $ http://test.com/test/
```

Will I need to do a reverse proxy and then re-write from there?

EDIT: I apologize, i should have explained a little better.
site.example.com is owned by test.com (company A). So we changed the CNAME to point to site.devEnvironment.com ( companyB.com )

and test.com/test is our server and dir, trying to rewrite the URL to be test.com/test instead of site.example.com

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it belongs on [Server Fault](https://serverfault.com)

Comment: Tomcat doesn't use **.htaccess**.

Answer (score 0):

Try using this:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^site\.example\.com$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/site/
RewriteRule (.*) /test/$1
```

This should make it so that your subdomain is hidden and `test` is written as a directory. Make sure you clear your cache before testing this.

Comment: Thanks for your response Thickguru, i've made the change with your suggestion jsut to see waht would happen but nothing changed even after clearing the cache